# apache is crashing not working for a php framework

Tags: php, apache2

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/sachin/neuu-dashboard/Telemetry_Backend/www

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /home/sachin/neuu-dashboard/Telemetry_Backend/www>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            #Order deny,allow
            #Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

my apache is keep on crashing when am setting up a php framework

1. apache is working fine when it is pointing to a default var/www/html
2. after  changing the path it asked enmod and rewrite that also i did but still it is crashing
3. as soon as i restarted on the very 1st request it crashed

the error code is below from error.log
    [Sun Dec 09 13:04:31.953572 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24209] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 09 13:04:32.048381 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24328] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 09 13:04:32.048453 2018] [core:notice] [pid 24328] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

help me out to set up the php framework

Comment: I do not see a crash... a SIGTERM means it has been shut down.

Comment: apart from that, what do you mean by "after changing the path it asked enmod and rewrite that also i did but still it is crashing"?

Comment: @arkascha yes it is keep on shutting down what might be the issue

Comment: i enabled  ` sudo a2enmod headers`, `sudo a2enmod rewrite`